# Subsetting unique values within for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to calculate proportion of time a shark spends at specific depths.

My dataset is like this:

```
    deployID depth         datetime       date
   1        A  66.5 18/03/2018 00:00 18/03/2018
   2        A  55.0 18/03/2018 00:02 18/03/2018
   3        A  28.5 18/03/2018 00:05 18/03/2018
   4        A  23.5 18/03/2018 00:07 19/03/2018
   5        A  48.5 18/03/2018 00:10 19/03/2018
   6        A  53.5 18/03/2018 00:12 19/03/2018
```

but `df1$date` runs until 26/6/2018. Each day has 576 observations, one every 2.5 minutes.

I have written a simple function to calculate the proportion for a given date:

```
pct.day <- function(a.depth) {
  part.day <- length(a.depth$datetime) / length(sharkA$datetime)
  return(part.day)
}
```

and a for loop which I hoped would calculate this for every day listed in `df1`.

```
uniq.day = unique(df1$date)
prop_day = list()
for(i in 1:length(uniq.day)){
  day =  subset(df1, date == [[i]])
  sharkA = subset(day, deployID=="A")
  a = subset(sharkA, depth<70 & depth >30)
  prop_day[[i]] <- with(day, pct.day(a))
  m <- data.frame(unlist(prop_day))
}
```

However, I am running into some errors. Firstly, I am getting `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"` when I run the for loop. I am not sure that I am properly subsetting each individual day in

```
for(i in 1:length(uniq.day)){
  day =  subset(df1, date == [[i]])
}
```

I would like it to output the result of the function for 18/3/2018 and 19/3/2018 in `m`, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: This just "looks wrong": `date == [[i]]`. Two square-brackets is an infix function and you have not put in a "left-hand side". Seems to me that it should have throw an error. And you should now read how to [edit], then copy the code from your comment up into you question body, and delete this comment. Comments are not supposed to be used by questioners for code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a loop and performing the multiple subsetting options there are better R options such as the `split` function along `lapply`.

Another faster option is using the dplyr package.  This package is very handy for these types of problems.  Here is a possible single line solution:

```
df<-structure(list(deployID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
    depth = c(66.5, 55, 28.5, 23.5, 48.5, 53.5), datetime = c("18/03/2018 00:00", 
    "18/03/2018 00:02", "18/03/2018 00:05", "18/03/2018 00:07", 
    "18/03/2018 00:10", "18/03/2018 00:12"), date = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("18/03/2018", "19/03/2018"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(deployID, date) %>% summarize(targetdepth=sum(depth<70 & depth>30 ), total=n(), targetdepth/total)

 #deployID date       targetdepth total `targetdepth/total`
 #<fct>    <fct>            <int> <int>               <dbl>
 #A        18/03/2018           2     3               0.667
 #A        19/03/2018           2     3               0.667
```

Here the group_by function is performing the subsetting by both the day and deployID, then it is calculating the number of cases <70 and >30 and dividing by the total number of cases in each subset.

This is also significantly faster than using a loop.

Comment: Thank you! However when I apply this to my full dataset, I seem to be getting some errors. Most of the `targetdepth/total` values are coming up as NA, but when I look at them through subsetting they should have values instead of NA- eg deployID A on 18/3/18 has 576 total records, with 392 in the target range which should be 0.6805556, but it comes up as NA.

Comment: @Fionn, Is it possible that some of your depths are NA? It that is the case then the `sum` function will generate the NA.  You can try adding `na.rm = TRUE` to the sum function to handle these cases.